# Maven Jackson-Databind

Tags: maven, jackson

I use such pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But realy in my project I have

jackson-annotaions 2.8.0
jackson-core 2.8.9

Why jackson-annotaions is 2.8.0 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jackson-databind library uses two other libraries: jackson-core and jackson-annotations. The FasterXML team (the makers of Jackson) release these libraries independently so they have their own version numbers. This just happens to be the version that was used by jackson-databind when 2.8.9 was released.